# What is the correct syntax to run cron every 4 hours?

Tags: cron

I have the following syntax (which I think is correcT?) but it runs the command every minute!

```
* */4 * * * /cmd.sh
```

Comment: 0 */4 * * * /cmd.sh - your problem was the * in the first column.

Answer (score 81, accepted):

```
0 0,4,8,12,16,20 * * * /cmd.sh
```

That's probably how I would do it.  This will run the job every 4 hours, on the hours of 00:00, 04:00, 08:00 12:00, 16:00, 20:00.

This is just a little more verbose way of writing */4, but it should work the same.

Comment: Yeah i really like this way its super easy to read.

Answer (score 82):

The original post, prior to editing, showed the configuration as:

- */4 * * * /cmd.sh

The poster wasn't familiar with Markdown and put an asterisk in the first column, causing it to appear as a bullet. I edited their post to reflect what they intended to post:

```
* */4 * * * /cmd.sh
```

In that configuration the poster would get the behavior they observed: The job will run once per minute during hours that are evenly divisible by 4.

To avoid running once per minute a number is needed in the first column, like this:

```
15 * * * * whatever...
```

That will run on the 15th minute after every hour.

Putting that all together: To run once per hour during hours that are evenly divisible by 4 use this syntax:

```
15 */4 * * * whatever...
```

Comment: You must have misread the question, the command is supposed to run every four hours, not four times per hour.

Comment: His original formatting made it look wrong. Look at my edits.

Comment: Evan is correct. 0 */4 * * * <cmd> would run on the hour every 4th hour.

Answer (score 29):

Do a crontab -e and then add the following entry

0 */4 * * *  path_to_the_script

This will the script every 4 hours.

Answer (score 10):

The problem is the * in the first column

> '  * */2 * * * /path-to-script  '

this translates into run each minute of the hour, but only do it every 2 hours